# Setting the initial position in select does not work

Tags: laravel, if-statement, view, laravel-blade

I want to display it in a loop for @foreach and display the corresponding one at the beginning

```
<label for="user_name">employee</label>
<select name="user_name">
    <option value="{!!null!!}" @if($param['user_name'] == '') selected @endif>no</option>
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <option value="{{$user->name}}" @if($param['user_name'] == '{{$user->name}}') selected @endif>{{$user->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

However, this is not a good choice

Is there no good way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `{{}}` or echo the variable inside of @if directive like we donot compare the value in simple PHP by echo the variable.
So @if can be written simply as :

```
@if($param['user_name'] == $user->name)
```

and you need to re-write second option like inside the foreach like:

```
<option value="{{$user->name}}" @if($param['user_name'] == $user->name) selected @endif>{{$user->name}}</option>
```

Hope it works for you now.